# First CSS selector does not work as expected

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm new in web designing. Something really strange happened while I was trying to work on my first CSS. the first selector in external style sheet doesn't work! For example:

```
p {
    color:red;
}
body {
    color:blue; 
}
section {
    background-color:black;
}
```

doesn't lead to red colored paragraphs, but when I change the order of selectors for example:

```
body {
    color:blue; 
}
p {
    color:red;
}
section {background-color:black;
}
```

the same thing happens for body color and paragraph color turns to red!
has something like this happened to you before?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w87deb9n/. Are those your only CSS rules?

Comment: this is quite not possible! can you share you html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to CSS rule that the `body` selector must be in the top of other selectors.....,
But, This is not Possible, I put any selector anywhere but it works!
But don't worry if it works for you keep `body` selector at *top*

Answer (score 0):

The order is important, cause css, html, js is parsed from top to bottom
if you put next CSS in file

```
p {
 color: blue;
}
p {
 color: red;

}
```

color will be red, if you need to set something permanently, I mean it's not overwritten with CSS below then use keyword !important

```
p {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend you stay away from using the !important keyword as someone new to css.